# "Proxime" vs. "proximate"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

When should *proxime* and *proximate* be used? Can they be used both to mean *spatial* as well as *temporal* nearness? Are they being used differently in British and American English?

Comment: I've never seen *proxime* in English, except in Latin tags. *Proximate* is used only in formal English, in both spatial and temporal senses, and usually in some technical sense: "proximate cause" in law, "proximate marker" in linguistics.

Comment: Also in biomed speak when talking about distal and proximate stuff, e.g., "proximate genotoxins, i. e. xenobiotics" and "a new tumor appearing < 2 cm proximate to the primary lesion".

Comment: *proximate*: ~in the neighborhood *proxime*: immediate neighbor. Neither seems to have inherent spatial or temporal connotations that limit usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Proxime* is often defined only to have the sense of *proximate* that refers to the next or previous item in a series. If you want to be clear that you mean this sense, it may serve well.

It is however marked as obsolete in many dictionaries, so it may be best not to use it at all.

Comment: *To be clear of* means *to avoid*.

Comment: @jwpat7 thanks, that could be interpreted validly two different ways. I've edited to hopefully be clearer that I mean a reason to use it in the first sentence, though my reason for suggesting you don't in the second is stronger, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Like Stoney, I have never seen *proxime* in English.  But, then, I wasn't around in 1820...

[image]

Comment: Just for grins I checked out the citations of *proxime* in the 1809-10 period. All but 4 were in Latin passages; the four were in works on logic, contrasting *proxime* (in italics) with *remote*, and glossing it as *immediate*. Checking every fifth page in the 1945-2000 results yielded only Latin results.